# Getting attendance record for 12 Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

here is my table Structure

```
tbl_fullleaves:

leaveID(int)
EmpID(int)     
Normalleaves(double)
SSL(double)
MonthId(int)
YearId(int)

----
monthid =1 for jan , monthid = 2 for feb so on
yearid = 1 from where i started leaves incremental on yearly
```

### Data in form :

[image: Data Formate in sql]

Need to Display:

```
Empid Normalleave_jan SSl_jan Normalleave_feb SSl_feb Normalleave_mar SSl_mar

2        3.25          4.5      3.75            0        0              4.5
```

Comment: You want to PIVOT the information, presumably? There's a few ways you can do it but it's not very hard to find if you search for `PIVOT SQL SERVER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's most popular method for transposing data in SQL:

```
select EmpID,
   max(case when MonthID = 1 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_jan,
   max(case when MonthID = 1 then [SSL] end) as SSL_jan,
   max(case when MonthID = 2 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_feb,
   max(case when MonthID = 2 then [SSL] end) as SSL_feb,
   max(case when MonthID = 3 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_mar,
   max(case when MonthID = 3 then [SSL] end) as SSL_mar,
   max(case when MonthID = 4 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_apr,
   max(case when MonthID = 4 then [SSL] end) as SSL_apr,
   max(case when MonthID = 5 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_may,
   max(case when MonthID = 5 then [SSL] end) as SSL_may,
   max(case when MonthID = 6 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_jun,
   max(case when MonthID = 6 then [SSL] end) as SSL_jun,
   max(case when MonthID = 7 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_jul,
   max(case when MonthID = 7 then [SSL] end) as SSL_jul,
   max(case when MonthID = 8 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_aug,
   max(case when MonthID = 8 then [SSL] end) as SSL_aug,
   max(case when MonthID = 9 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_sep,
   max(case when MonthID = 9 then [SSL] end) as SSL_sep,
   max(case when MonthID = 10 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_oct,
   max(case when MonthID = 10 then [SSL] end) as SSL_oct,
   max(case when MonthID = 11 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_nov,
   max(case when MonthID = 11 then [SSL] end) as SSL_nov,
   max(case when MonthID = 12 then NormalLeave end) as NormalLeave_dec,
   max(case when MonthID = 12 then [SSL] end) as SSL_dec
from tbl_fullleaves
group by EmpID
```